# Dynamically create and populate input radio with PHP

Tags: php, html, loops

I'm currently working with PHP and HTML, I'm making a multiple choise exam, the PHP file contains four arrays, the first one storage the questions, the second one storages the probable answers for option "a)", the third one storages the probable answers for option "b)" and finally  the last one storages the answers for option "c)"

Here his the code to create and populate both the questions and the multiple choises.

```
for($i=0; $i<20; $i++){
    echo "$i.".$preguntas[$i]."<BR>";
    echo"<input type = 'radio'  name='R$i'>a)".$r1[$i]."<br>";
    echo"<input type = 'radio'  name='R$i'>b)".$r2[$i]."<br>";
    echo"<input type = 'radio'  name='R$i'>c)".$r3[$i]."<br>";
    echo "<BR><BR>";

}
```

I'm having some troubles to make this work, any idea how coud I grade the correct answers

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider adding questions and their potential answers to one multidimensional array. This will make it easier to match correct answers. And therefore edit your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
<?php
echo "<pre>";
var_export($_POST['R']);
echo "</pre>";
for($i=0; $i<20; $i++){
    echo "$i.".$preguntas[$i]."<BR>";
    echo"<input type='radio' name='R[$i]' value='a'>a){$r1[$i]}<br>";
    echo"<input type='radio' name='R[$i]' value='b'>b){$r2[$i]}<br>";
    echo"<input type='radio' name='R[$i]' value='c'>c){$r3[$i]}<br>";
    echo "<BR><BR>";
}
?>
<button>submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll receive something like:

```
array (
  0 => 'a',
  1 => 'b',
  2 => 'b',
)
```

For example:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
<?php
$questions = [
    [
        'question' => 'Who was first programmer?',
        'answers' => [
            'a' => 'Alan Turing',
            'b' => 'Ada Lovelace',
            'c' => 'Rasmus Lerdorf',
            'd' => 'James Bond',
        ],
        'correctAnswer' => 'b',
    ],
    [
        'question' => 'Who created php?',
        'answers' => [
            'a' => 'Alan Turing',
            'b' => 'Ada Lovelace',
            'c' => 'Rasmus Lerdorf',
        ],
        'correctAnswer' => 'c',
    ],
    [
        'question' => 'Who created Turing machine?',
        'answers' => [
            'a' => 'David Beckham',
            'b' => 'Rasmus Lerdorf',
            'c' => 'Floyd Mayweather, Jr.',
            'd' => 'Ada Lovelace',
            'e' => 'Alan Turing',
        ],
        'correctAnswer' => 'e',
    ],
];
if (!empty($_POST['response'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['response'] as $questionId => $answerKey) {
        echo '<h5>'.$questions[$questionId]['question'].'</h5>';
        if ($questions[$questionId]['correctAnswer'] === $answerKey) {
            echo 'Correct answer.<br>';
        } else {
            echo 'Wrong answer.<br>';
        }
    }
} else {
    foreach ($questions as $questionId => $data) {
        echo '<h5>'.$data['question'].'</h5>';
        foreach ($data['answers'] as $key => $answer) {
            echo '<input type="radio" name="response['.$questionId.']" value="'.$key.'">'.$key.') '.$answer.'<br>';
        }
        echo "<br><br>";
    }
}
?>
<button>submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You can tweak it [here](http://runnable.com/VTnQ4vCft9wN987h/online-test-for-php)

Comment: Hi mister, I have a question, whay does you code return an array and how could I manipulate the elements of it so that I can get some statistics. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it like this:

```
foreach ($preguntas as $key => $pregunta) {
  echo ($key + 1) . '. ' . $pregunta . '<br />';
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    echo '<input type="radio" name="answerForQuestion' . $key . '" value="' . ${'r' . $i}[$key] . '" /><br />'
  }
  echo '<br /><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why answers have to be in different arrays. One array for exam data is enough. Look at below code.

This is my solution for your problem. See comments (I explained what every part of it does) and try to understand it.

```
<?php

// Set questions and answers
$questions = array(
    // First question
    array(
        'question' => 'Question 1?',
        // Possible answers for first question
        'answers'  => array(
            array(
                'answer'  => 'Answer option 1',
                'correct' => false
            ),
            array(
                'answer'  => 'Answer option 2',
                'correct' => true
            ),
            array(
                'answer'  => 'Answer option 3',
                'correct' => false
            ),
        )
    ),
    // Second question
    array(
        'question' => 'Question 2?',
        // Possible answers for second question
        'answers'  => array(
            array(
                'answer'  => 'Answer option 1',
                'correct' => false
            ),
            array(
                'answer'  => 'Answer option 2',
                'correct' => false
            ),
            array(
                'answer'  => 'Answer option 3',
                'correct' => true
            ),
        )
    )
);

// Print form
echo '<form method="POST">';

$i = 1;

foreach ($questions as $question_key => $questionArray) {
    echo $i.'. '.$questionArray['question'].'<br />';

    // Answers will be POSTed in one array (answerForQuestion)
    // answerForQuestion array keys would be questions keys. 
    // Values would be keys to our answers array.
    // So we can easily check for correct answers. See below.
    foreach ($questionArray['answers'] as $answer_key => $answerArray) {
        echo '<input id="question_'.$question_key.'_'.$answer_key.'" type="radio" name="answerForQuestion['.$question_key.']" value="'.$answer_key.'"> <label for="question_'.$question_key.'_'.$answer_key.'">'.$answerArray['answer'].'</label><br />';
    }

    echo '<br /><br />';

    // Increase questions order number.
    $i++;
}

echo '<input type="submit" name="go" value="Answer!">';
echo '</form>';

// Check for answers, if user POSTed data.

if($_POST['go']){

    // Get count of questions
    $questionsCount      = count($questions);

    // This will be increased with correct answer
    $correctAnswersCount = 0;

    // Check for every question.
    // This will quarantee that empty answer will be considered as false.
    // Assuming that every question has correct answer.
    foreach ($questions as $question_key => $questionArray) {

        // Get answer key. Key of our array, so we can easily find selected answer
        $answer_key = $_POST['answerForQuestion'][$question_key];

        // Get selected answer array
        $answerArray = $questionArray['answers'][$answer_key];

        // If is correct
        if($answerArray['correct']){
            echo 'Your answer for question "'.$questionArray['question'].'" is correct!<br />';
            $correctAnswersCount++;
        }
        else{
            echo 'Your answer for question "'.$questionArray['question'].'" is incorrect!<br />';
        }

    }

    // Just for statistics. Not in your question, but wount hurt
    echo '<br />Correct answers: '.$correctAnswersCount.' out of '.$questionsCount.'. Result: '.round($correctAnswersCount / $questionsCount * 100).'%';

}

?>
```