# How to use PHP count++ function to count the marks of a quiz?

Tags: php, html, count

I'm working on a quiz. I want to count the total score obtained by a user after the user has submitted their attempt. How to create a result page that show the marks obtained by the user after they submitted the answer. How do I get the total marks such that each correct answer they get 1/(total number of questions in a quiz)?

This is what I have so far and I can't seem to get it working.

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($quizHistoryQ as $index => $arr){
    if($count++ == 1) continue;

}
```

This is my question script

```
<?php

$Titles = array("quizHistoryQ"=>"History Quiz", "quizMathQ" =>" Math Quiz", "quizHTMLq" => "HTML Quiz"); 

$quizHistoryQ = [
    "Q1" => ["questions"=>"ABC?",
        "options" => ["this is option 1",
        "this is option 2",
        "this is option 3"],
        "answer" =>2
    ],
    "Q2" => ["questions"=>"This is the Question String for question 2",
        "options" => ["this is option A",
        "this is option B",
        "this is option C"],
        "answer" =>1
    ],
    "Q3" =>["questions"=>"This is the Question String for question 3",
        "options" => ["this is option X",
        "this is option Y",
        "this is option Z"],
        "answer" =>0
    ]
];

echo 'Title:'. $Titles['quizHistoryQ'];

foreach( $quizHistoryQ as $index => $arr ){
    $question=$arr['questions'];
    $options=$arr['options'];
    $answer=$arr['answer']; 

    echo '<h3>Question: '.$index.': '.$question.'</h3>';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($options as $i => $options) {
        echo " <br> <input type='radio' name='{$index}[]' value='{$i}'/>{$options}";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you check whether they gave the correct answer?

Comment: I have answered similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29691847/dynamically-create-and-populate-input-radio-with-php/29693537#29693537). Not exactly like your's, but you can see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This question is one I have seen before - perhaps then the following should help.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>quiz</title>
        <style>
            form{ display:block; float:none; width:90%; margin:1rem auto; box-sizing:content-box; padding:1rem; border:1px solid black; }
            ul{}
            li{}
            h3{ margin:1rem auto; }
            section{margin:1rem auto;}
            section:nth-of-type(odd){background:whitesmoke;}
            output{margin:2rem auto;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

        $quizHistoryQ = array(
            "q1" => array(
                "question"=>"This is the First question",
                "options" => array(
                    "this is option 1",
                    "this is option 2",
                    "this is option 3"
                ),
                "answer" => 2
            ),

           "q2" => array(
                "question"=>"This is the Question String for question 2",
                "options" => array(
                    "this is option A",
                    "this is option B",
                    "this is option C"
                ),
                "answer" => 1
            ),

            "q3" =>array(
                "question"=>"This is the Question String for question 3",
                "options" => array(
                    "this is option X",
                    "this is option Y",
                    "this is option Z"
                ),
                "answer" => 0
            )
        );



        echo "
        <form name='quiz' method='post'>";

        foreach( $quizHistoryQ as $index => $arr ){

            $question=$arr['question'];
            $options=$arr['options'];
            $answer=$arr['answer']; 

            echo '<h3>Question: '.$index.': '.$question.'</h3>';
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach( $options as $i => $option ) echo "<li><input type='radio' name='{$index}[]' value='{$i}'/>{$option}";
            echo '</ul>';
        }

        echo "
            <input type='submit' name='sub' value='Submit'/>
        </form>";




        if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

            $points=0;

            foreach( $_POST as $i => $answer ) {
                if( $i!=='sub' ){

                    $success='Incorrect';
                    $option=$answer[0];

                    $answer=$quizHistoryQ[ $i ]['options'][ $option ];
                    $question=$quizHistoryQ[ $i ]['question'];
                    $correct=$quizHistoryQ[ $i ]['answer'];



                    if( intval( $correct )===intval( $option ) ){
                        $points++;
                        $success='Correct'; 
                    }

                    echo '<section>Question[ '.$i.' ]: '.$question.' - Your Answer: '.$answer.' [ '.$success.' ]</section>';
                }
            }
            echo '<output>You scored:'. $points.'/'.count($quizHistoryQ).'</output>';
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```